# Combining standard errors of two separate variables

Tags: weights, weighted-regression, weighted-data

I have a dependent variable associated with a SE and an independent variable associated with a SE. I would like to weight my regression such that both of these SEs are taken into account. What is the most kosher way for me to create this weight? Thank you for any help.

The dependent variable is effect sizes (measured as RR) obtained from randomized controlled trials and SE associated with these effect sizes. The independent variable is reporting odds ratios obtained from a pharmacovigilance database,ie, particular side effect of a drug / total side effects reported for that drug, and SE associated with these ROR. The regression planned is a linear meta-regression.

Comment: We need the details of how you obtained these SE and what kind of regression you plan, as well as some summary information about the data: all these (at a minimum) go into determining what a suitable answer would be.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I updated the post with the requested information.

Comment: Thank you.  It really helps to have *quantitative* information.  One important fact is that you don't have to worry about the SEs of the regressor(s) until they become an appreciable fraction of the regressor ranges.  At that point, you need some form of errors-in-variables regression.  If you don't, whether you use the SEs of the response variable depends on its magnitude relative to the residual variation in the response.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Is it possible to do a an "errors-in-variables" meta-regression? I have never seen this before. Another option that was floated to me was to only apply the dependent variable SE weights and then do a robustness analysis in which the 95% CI interval values are run as the independent variable. Does this also sound like a reasonable approach to you?

Comment: Although that strategy is tempting, it has a terrible pitfall: the SEs of the dependent values are not the correct weights to use (unless you believe the dependent values are independent of all the regressors!).  Using them can produce grossly incorrect results.  I see nothing conceptually problematic with an errors-in-variables meta-regression.

Comment: Okay, interesting. What constitutes the dependent values as being independent of all the regressors? The dependent values are effect sizes drawn from studies unrelated to the database where the independent variable values are drawn from, so this may be the case in this regression? I suppose my issue then is that I don't know if I have the chops to do an errors-in-variables meta-regression. For one, I am an SPSS user. Where does one find support for such a complex analysis?

Comment: If you think the variables are independent, you believe the meta-analysis is useless.  You are doing this because you hope there *is* some relationship to be found!

Comment: Got it. Would you mind further explaining why using the SE for the dependent variables as weights while testing the interval ranges for the independent variable using it's 95 percent CIs is incorrect?

Comment: The weights need to reflect the variabilities of the responses.  There would be a lot of variability even with perfect measurements--you have to account for that along with the measurement error.  Otherwise, the algorithms will overemphasize data with low measurement errors.

Comment: Whuber, I cannot find anyone anywhere who knows how to do what you suggest. Do you think it is actually possible to implement?